# Setting personalized FocusTraversalPolicy on tab in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, focus, jtabbedpane

After solving the issue of the background image, I've really come into a no go with trying to change the Focus policy.

I create the class and override the methods like this:

```
package tab;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MyOFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy{

    Vector<Component> order;

    public MyOFocusTraversalPolicy(Vector<Component> order) {
        this.order = new Vector<Component>(order.size());
        this.order.addAll(order);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
            Component aComponent) {
        int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1);// % order.size();
        System.out.println("Estoy en el getComponentAfter, numero: "+idx);
        System.out.println("El tamaño del vector es de:"+order.size());
        return order.get(idx);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
            Component aComponent) {
        int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
        if (idx == 0) {
            idx = order.size() - 1;
        }
        return order.get(idx);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.lastElement();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
        return order.get(1);
    }

}
```

And I make the vector with all the components in the tab and declare a new Object of MyOFocusTraversalPolicy, like this:

```
Vector<Component> order = new Vector<Component>(14);
            order.add(rBtnHombre);
            order.add(rBtnMujer);
            order.add(spinEdad);
            order.add(slider);
            order.add(txtUser);
            order.add(txtPass);
            order.add(txtConfirmPass);
            order.add(txtNombre);
            order.add(txtApellidos);
            order.add(cBoxProvincias);
            order.add(cBoxTipoCalle);
            order.add(txtDireccion);
            order.add(txtCP);
            order.add(txtMail);

            newPolicyDatos = new MyOFocusTraversalPolicy(order);
            datos.setFocusTraversalPolicy(newPolicyDatos);
```

Yet it has no effect.

May the problem be because "datos" is one of three tabs that belong to a JTabbedPane, for anything else I've ran out of ideas, and I can't find no specific information about FocusTraversalPolicy on tabs.

I have set a print in the getComponentAfter and it doesn't show when tabbing through the components

Hope someone has tried this before and can give me a hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is way overdue, but I've been trying something similar recently and wondered why the traverse doesn't work like I set it.

The missing line for me was:

```
myJTabbedPane.add(outerMostJPanel);
outerMostJPanel.setFocusCycleRoot(true); // magic-line
outerMostJPanel.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MyFocusTraversalPolcy(...));
```

Hope this helps.